# (POO), Envio y Captura de Informacion no funciona bien

Tags: javascript, html5, poo

buen dia, estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto aplicando conocimientos adquiridos en programacion orientada a objetos, la pequeña aplicacion funciona **"pero de una manera extraña"**. se ha creado un formulario en el cual esta la opcion de elegir que tipo de usario se va a crear (profesor o alumno), la informacion se puede ingresar correctamente, pero si selecciono de primeras el tipo de usuario alumno al momento de dar click al boton crear usuario(submit) la informacion no se envia y no se imprime en el DOM; Lo mas extraño es que si elijo al tipo de usuario profesor de primeras si me envia e inserta la informacion, luego cuando vuelvo a cambiar el tipo de usario por alumno ahi si me imprime la informacion que le asigne al tipo alumno

Agradezco muchisimo si alguien me puedise orientar y ayudarme a descubrir y a corregir este funcionamiento tan extraño.

Adjunto link para la descarga del proyecto por si alguien lo quiere ver mas detallado: https://we.tl/t-9pWt7bGWO5

```js
import Curso from "./Classes/Curso.js";
import Alumno from "./Classes/Alumno.js";
import Profesor from "./Classes/Profesor.js";


const contenedor = document.getElementById('Cursos')

//funcion que crea e inserta nuevos cursos en el DOM  desde el objeto cursos
const MostrarCursos = (curso) => {
    const hijos = document.createElement('div',)
    hijos.classList.add('card', 'm-mb-1') //asigna las clases de los estilos que contendran cada uno de los hijos
    contenedor.appendChild(hijos)
    hijos.innerHTML = `
     <div class="img-container s-ratio-16-9 s-radius-tr s-radius-tl">
    <img src="${curso.getPoster()}" alt="${curso.getNombre()}"\>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card__data s-border s-radius-br s-radius-bl s-pxy-2">
        <h3 class="t5 s-mb-2 s-center">${curso.getNombre()}</h3>
       <div class="s-mb-2 s-main-center">
        <span class="small">Cantidad de clases: ${curso.getClases()}</span>
        </div>
    </div>`
}

// evento que crea los cursos tomando los valores e imprimiendolos desde el DOM con el boton Crear curso
const formulario = document.getElementById('formCursos')
formulario.addEventListener('submit', evento =>{
    evento.preventDefault()
    const capturaEnvio = evento.target
    const curso = new Curso(capturaEnvio.nombreCurso.value, capturaEnvio.posterCurso.value, capturaEnvio.clasesCurso.value)
    MostrarCursos(curso)
})

/*evento que valida si el usuario a registarse es profesor o alumno, el evento muestra u oculta algunos campos del
 formulario dependiendo la condicion que se cumpla */
const tipoUsuario = document.getElementById('tipoUsuario')
const cursosDictados= document.getElementById('cursosDictados')
const calificacion = document.getElementById('calificacionProfesor')
const cursosTomados = document.getElementById('cursosTomados')
const cursoInsertado = document.getElementById('insertadoCurso')
tipoUsuario.addEventListener('change', ev =>{
    if (tipoUsuario.value==="Profesor"){
        tablaProfes.style.display=""
        tablaAlumnos.style.display="none"
        cursosDictados.style.display=""
        calificacion.style.display=""
        cursosTomados.style.display="none"
        cursoInsertado.style.display="none"
    }else{
        tablaProfes.style.display="none"
        tablaAlumnos.style.display=""
        cursosDictados.style.display="none"
        calificacion.style.display="none"
        cursosTomados.style.display=""
        cursoInsertado.style.display=""
    }
})

//evento click que inserta desde un boton un curso tomado por el alumno
const btnAgregarCurso = document.getElementById('btnAgregarCurso')
const insertoCurso = document.getElementById('insertadoCurso')
const seleccionarCurso = document.getElementById('seleccionarCurso')
btnAgregarCurso.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    insertoCurso.value=seleccionarCurso.value
})

//funcion que crea los valores de Alumnos y profesor dependiendo de la condicion que se cumpla
const tablaAlumnos = document.getElementById('tablaAlumnos')
const contenedorTabla = document.getElementById('contenidoTablaAlumnos')
const tablaProfes = document.getElementById('tablaProfes')
const contTablaProfes = document.getElementById('contenidoTablaProfes')
const MostrarUsuarios = (usuarios)=>{
    const tabla = document.createElement('tr')
    switch (tipoUsuario.value) {
        case "Profesor":
            contTablaProfes.appendChild(tabla)
            tabla.innerHTML=`
          <td>${usuarios.getNombres()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getApellidos()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getCorreo()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getActivo()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getCursosDictados()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getCalificacion()}</td>
        `
            break

        case "Alumno":
            contenedorTabla.appendChild(tabla)
            tabla.innerHTML=`
          <td>${usuarios.getNombres()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getApellidos()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getCorreo()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getActivo()}</td>
          <td>${usuarios.getCursosTomados()}</td>
        `
    }

}

//funcion que captura los valores de los input, valida el checkbox, e imprime un nuevo usuario segun la condicion
// que se cumpla
const formularioTabla = document.getElementById('formTabla')
formularioTabla.addEventListener('submit', evento =>{
    evento.preventDefault()
    const capturaEnvio = evento.target
     if(capturaEnvio.activoUsuario.checked === true){
         capturaEnvio.activoUsuario.value= "Si es activo"
     }else{
         capturaEnvio.activoUsuario.value= "No es activo"
     }

    //evalua el tipo de usuario seleccionado para saber en que usuario imprimir la informacion
    switch (tipoUsuario.value) {
        case "Profesor":
            const profesor = new Profesor(capturaEnvio.nombreUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.apellidoUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.correoUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.activoUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.Dictados.value, capturaEnvio.calificacionProfe.value)
            MostrarUsuarios(profesor)
            break
        case "Alumno":
            const estudiante = new Alumno(capturaEnvio.nombreUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.apellidoUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.correoUsuario.value, capturaEnvio.activoUsuario.value,capturaEnvio.cursoInsertado.value)
            MostrarUsuarios(estudiante)
            console.log('bien')
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Proyecto Poo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ux.ed.team/css/styles.css?201803301710"> <!-- libreria Ed-grid-->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="ed-grid">
        <h1>Aplicacion De Registros Para Cursos</h1>
    </div>
<!-- inicio del menu de navegacion tipo tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills ed-grid m-grid-2 m-mb-4" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item ed-grid" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home"
                    type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Crear Cursos</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ed-grid" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile"
                    type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Crear Usuarios</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- Inicio boton formulario cursos -->
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
            <div class="ed-grid m-grid-2">
                <form id="formCursos">
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Nombre Del Curso
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa Aqui El Nombre Del curso" name="nombreCurso" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Poster
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa Aqui La URL Del Poster" name="posterCurso" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Cantidad De Clases
                            <input type="number" min="1" name="clasesCurso" style="-webkit-appearance:textfield" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Crear Curso">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="ed-grid m-grid-4 s-grid-2" id="Cursos"></div>
        </div>

<!--   inicio boton Alumnos   -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
            <div class="ed-grid m-grid-2">
                <form id="formTabla">
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Nombres
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa Aqui El Nombre Del Usuario" name="nombreUsuario"
                                   required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Apellidos
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa Aqui Los Apellidos" name="apellidoUsuario" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2">
                            Correo Electronico
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Ejemplo@correo" name="correoUsuario" required>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Seleccione El tipo De Usuario
                            <select name="selectorUsuario" id="tipoUsuario">
                                <option value="Alumno">Alumno</option>
                                <option value="Profesor">Profesor</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2" id="cursosTomados">
                            Elije un curso
                            <select name="TomadosCursos" class="m-mb-2" id="seleccionarCurso">
                                <option value="Html Desde cero">Html Desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Css Desde Cero">Css desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Javascript Desde Cero">Javascript Desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Git Desde Cero">Git Desde Cero</option>
                            </select>

                            <div class="button m-to-right" id="btnAgregarCurso">Agregar Cursos</div>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="text" name="cursoInsertado" id="insertadoCurso">
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2" id="cursosDictados" style="display: none">
                            Cursos Dictados
                            <select name="Dictados">
                                <option value="Html Desde cero">Html Desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Css Desde Cero">Css desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Javascript Desde Cero">Javascript Desde Cero</option>
                                <option value="Git Desde Cero">Git Desde Cero</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2" id="calificacionProfesor" style="display: none">
                            Califiacion Del Profesor
                            <input type="number" min="1" max="5" name="calificacionProfe" style="-webkit-appearance:textfield" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2" id="checkActivo">
                            Activo
                            <input type="checkbox" name="activoUsuario" id="validarCheck">
                        </label>
                        <label class="m-py-2 m-center">
                            <input class="button " type="submit" value="Crear Usuario">
                            <input class="button" type="reset" value="Restaurar formulario">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Tabla alumnos -->
            <table class="table-hover" id="tablaAlumnos">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Nombres</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Apellidos</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Correo</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Activo</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Cursos Tomados</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="contenidoTablaAlumnos">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- Tabla Profesores -->
            <table class="table-hover" id="tablaProfes" style="display: none">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Nombres</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Apellidos</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Correo</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Activo</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Cursos Dictados</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="m-center">Calificacion</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="contenidoTablaProfes">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="module" src="./Scripts/Index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La pregunta no debe depender de cuánto dure el proyecto en wetransfer, pastebin, github u otro sitio externo; recuerda que la idea también es que la solución le sirva a otros en el futuro así como te sirve a ti. Trata de poner en la pregunta lo que es relevante a tu problema en forma de Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable. Que si lo corremos con los datos que dices usar, podamos entender el problema que tienes.

Comment: El código va aquí, no en otro lado

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ok, les agradezco por las sugerencias que me han dado, el problema es que no logro identificar exactamente el problema, por eso me veo en la necesidad de adjuntar todo en un archivo descargable, como comentaba en la descripcion de la pregunta, la pequña aplicacion funciona, pero tiene ese defecto que no lro identificar en que parte del codigo esta

Comment: Para identificar un problema debes depurar el código. Y si no sabes depurar conviene aprender si no quieres perder días y hasta semanas o desanimarte en la programación tirando la toalla. Depurar significa en un primer momento ir probado cada dato hasta encontrar dónde está fallando. Empieza por ahí y cuando identifiques el problema si no logras resolverlo puedes abrir una pregunta en la indiques claramente el problema. Como comprenderás, es complicado meterese a analizar todo un código para hacer algo que te corresponde a ti que es depurar.